# HTML to PDF Creation in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

## Path : Vendor/dompdf

> > I am getting Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in C:\wamp\www\sms_app\app\Controller\SentMessagesController.php on line 313.

Why i am getting error? This is my code:

```
function example()
    {   
        //App::import('Vendor','dompdf',array('file'=>'dompdf'.DS.'dompdf_config.inc.php'));
        require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php');
        $html =
        '<html><body>'.
        '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
        'templating system.</p>'.
        '</body></html>';
        try{
            $this->dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e;
        }
        $papersize = "legal";
        $orientation = 'landscape';
        $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
        $this->dompdf->set_paper($papersize, $orientation);
        $this->dompdf->render();
    
        $output = $this->dompdf->output();
        file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);
    
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to determine what is supposed to be loading the class `DOMPDF` and ensure that the class exists before using it, i.e. [debug around here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/dompdf_config.inc.php#L330).

Comment: I suggest you use the wonderful [CakePDF](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message pretty clearly tells you what is wrong. Check the file(s) you include if the class exists in that file, I doubt it is there. If not figure out in which file the class is and load that file. Check how Dompdf is loading its files.

Answer (score 1):

This error clear says you missing a class so please check how actually importing class in your code.